# PyCharm 2021.1 "Find in Files" not working

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, find

Ever since I installed update to PyCharm 2021.1 my find usages and find in files features always return nothing found. Is there some settings that I'm missing that I suppose to set in this new version?

Comment: does this helps you ? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266462, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266391

Comment: Besides the 2 excellent links @DorianTurba contributed, carefully check what [scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-scopes.html) is set when you run search. There's a possibility you accidentally changed the scope and there simply aren't any search results in that scope.

Comment: For the scope it uses In Project

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is on Jetbrains's issue tracker here: [issue IDEA-266391](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266391).

> WORKAROUND
>
> Invoke File|Invalidate caches and select the following checkbox:[image]
> Find in files doesn't show occurrences in 2021.1
>
> Can't be workarounded by any custom VM option in 2021.1. Only cache
> invalidation helps.
>
> Build with fix is provided here:
> https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2021.1+latest+builds
> Starting from: IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1 Preview (build 211.7142.13),
> released on Apr 21, 2021